# Initializing a dynamically allocated array with a specific value in C

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic-allocation

So, I have dynamically allocated memory for an array and I want initialize all its values to a specific value (which is an element of an enumeration).

Here's what I've done so far:

```
    typedef enum{APPLE, BANANA, ORANGE} fruit;
    typedef struct Smoothie Smoothie;
    struct Smoothie {
        fruit* tab;
    };
```

This is all the structures I've defined so far. Now, to create the "Smoothie", I do the following:

```
    Smoothie init(size_t n) {
         Smoothie* juice = malloc(sizeof(Smoothie));
         if (juice == NULL) {
             //error msg in case the allocation has failed.
         }
         juice->tab = calloc(n, sizeof(fruit));
         if (juice->tab == NULL) {
              //error msg in case the allocation has failed.
         }
         memset(juice->tab, APPLE, n*sizeof(fruit));
         return *juice;
    }
```

My question is the following. From what I've been able to read on the internet, I know that  `calloc()` already initializes all the values of the array at 0. In an enumeration, all the elements have a numerical value (by default, my enumeration has the following values: `Apple = 0  BANANA = 1  ORANGE  = 2`). So, since I want to initialize all the values of my array to `APPLE`, is it very useful to use `memset()` ?

In other words, what happens if I do not use `memset()`? How can I be sure that the compiler will understand that the values in my array are `fruit` variables and not just integers?

PS: I know that I could use a loop ot initilize my array, but the whole point of this is to actually avoid using the loop.

Comment: `memset` would only work here if `sizeof(fruit) == 1`, which is not guaranteed at all.

Comment: `Smoothie init(size_t n)` Hmmm... are you sure that is what you want? I would expect `Smoothie* init(size_t n)` and just `return juice;`

Comment: "`Smoothie init(size_t n)` Hmmm... are you sure that is what you want? I would expect `Smoothie* init(size_t n)` and just `return juice`, ? " Yes I am sure. I want the combination, not a pointer to the combination after using the function. (Although I could do it your way, it doesn't really matter).

Comment: `Smoothie init(size_t n)` would be fine if `juice` was a local variable of type `Smoothie` instead of type `Smoothie *`. The current code leaks memory. In other words, replace `Smoothie *juice = malloc(sizeof(Smoothie));` with `Smoothie juice;`, replace `juice->tab` with `juice.tab` and replace `return *juice;` with `return juice;`.

Comment: @Skyris - as Ian Abbott writes: If you use `Smoothie init(size_t n)` you have a memory leak as the function returns a copy and then the `juice` pointer is lost. If you actually want to return a `Smoothie`don't allocate it dynamic. Just use a local variable.

Comment: @4386427 Ok. Then how am I supposed to only use the local variable ? I don't get it (Sorry, I'm new to C)

Comment: @Skyris `Smoothie* juice = malloc(sizeof(Smoothie));` -> `Smoothie juice;` and `return *juice;` -> `return juice;`

Comment: @4386427 Wait... Actually I have an idea. What if I do this: `Smoothie juice;` then `juice.tab = calloc(n,sizeof(fruit));` ?

Comment: @Skyris - yep, that's it. Correct it shall be `juice.tab` instead of `juice->tab`

Comment: @4386427 Thank you, I get it. One more question though. Is it really a good idea to return the combination then ? Wouldn't it be better to return a pointer ? (I guess that's what you were telling me at first). Because, I will be creating a copy of it. Is that right ?

Comment: @Skyris It's fine to return a struct. It is most likely less expensive than calling `malloc`. You return a pointer when you `malloc` an array of `Smoothie` but since you only have one, it's better just to return it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So, since I want to initialize all the values of my array to `APPLE`, is it very useful to use `memset()`?

No. `memset()` fills an area with a *byte* value. The size of an `enum` can vary, but it is normally an `int`, which is larger than a byte. You will fill your memory with something undefined. (Except of course for the enum member with the value `0`)

> How can I be sure that the compiler will understand that the values in my array are `fruit` variables and not just integers?

You already did that by declaring it of type `fruit`. But it doesn't help much, because the conversion between integer and enum value in C is implicit.

---

All in all, if you need to initialize memory to an enum value other than `0`, you will need to write a loop. If you indeed want the value corresponding to `0`, `calloc()` will do, it doesn't matter as `0` is still `0` :)

Comment: Just a question though. So let's say I don't use the `memset()`,and now that I have my array initialized at 0 everywhere, how do I make the compiler understand that each 0 is a `color` and not an `int` ? Do I have to do some kind of typecasting?

Comment: An enum uses an integer type for representation and all bits 0 means `0` in any integer type, so it's just the same.